# What is "18 C.J.S., Copyright and Literary Property, § 113"?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, legal-research, legal-citation

I am working on a research paper on copyright, and I was reading [O'Rourke vs. RKO Radio Pictures](https://law.justia.com/cases/federal/district-courts/FSupp/44/480/1875376/). It cites "18 C.J.S., Copyright and Literary Property, § 113". What is it citing?

Answer (score 5):

[Corpus Juris Secundum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_Juris_Secundum), available [here](https://store.legal.thomsonreuters.com/law-products/Legal-Encyclopedias/Corpus-Juris-Secundumreg/p/100001060) for a pretty penny.

Comment: How likely is it that the OP, or anyone else who needs to refer to this, could find a copy at a library?

Comment: By "library" I assume you mean "reasonable sized public library, about the size of Seattle public library". Zero percent (I checked). OTOH a university's law library, definitely. Or, Hathi Trust (online) – I think so (I would access it there but I'm not sure that it's generally open to the world as opposed to to me).

Comment: (Turns out that the Hathi holding is only vol 34: at https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.35112100813015&view=1up&seq=14)

Comment: @Someone A law school law library or a state supreme court law library would definitely have C.J.S., but it would be hit and miss at county court house or prison law libraries, and rare at even large public and university non-law libraries. Often even paid online legal research service subscription would apply a surcharge to a search of this treatise if it was available at all on a particular service. C.J.S. and similar secondary sources like A.L.R. and Am.Jur. where commonly used before computer searchable legal research services were available, but have withered in use since then.